# UIScrollView vs Auto Layout (in Interface Builder)

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, interface-builder, autolayout

UIScrollView doesn't work correctly with Auto Layouts. I have read a lot about how to create working scroll view in code but in my case it's created in Interface Builder.

The simplest example - we auto-scroll active text field to visible area when keyboard is shown. Sample  from Apple doesn't work, as well as many examples in internet (`contentInset` conflicts with auto-layout constraints).

So is there a working approach for this case: UIScrollView created in Interface Builder with enabled Auto Layouts changes `contentInset` and `contentOffset`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311045/uiscrollview-animation-of-height-and-contentoffset-jumps-content-from-bottom/19344402#19344402 - is it what you're looking for? It doesn't have a text field in the scroll view, but I think it'll be similar if it had.

Comment: I'm discovering GitHub sample from answer in your link. In my case `contentSize` of scroll view is zero (in spite of correct value in collection view from that sample).

Comment: Do you have any warnings in the Interface Builder? My guess is that a scroll view can't get its `contentSize`, because subviews aren't connected to the top and the bottom of the scroll view.

Comment: No warnings. From my experiments, table and collection views scroll right. The issue with `contentSize` is actual only for `UIScrollView`.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html maybe this document will help you. I use the `Pure Auto Layout Approach` in the app I'm working on right now and don't have any problems with it.

Comment: I already read it. There scroll view is created from code. Did you use "Pure layout approach" for scroll view from Interface Builder?

Comment: Yes. Can you post a sample project showing the part that doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Arkadiusz, I already switched to UITableView - in that case content offset is correct. Sorry, but I have no free time to test it on sample project. Thanks for your attention and link to GitHub project with working collection view.